# Suppose $f(x) = x \log x$. What is $f\left(\frac{x}{\log x} \right)$?

Tags: complex-analysis, logarithms

I am trying to simplify
$$
f\left(\frac{x}{\log x} \right) = \frac{x}{\log x} \log \left( \frac{x}{\log x}  \right) = \frac{x}{\log x} \left( \log x - \log (\log x) \right) = x - \frac{x \log \log x}{\log x}
$$

Is there any further simplification I can make for the last term? I don't see a way to make the $\log \log x$ term disappear.

This was in the context of complexity analysis. I'm essentially trying to show that $f\left(\frac{x}{\log x} \right) = O\left( x \right)$. I think the above expression shows that because we know that $\frac{\log \log x }{x} < 1$, but I'm just curious if there's a simplification.

Comment: I would write it as $(1-\frac{\log\log x}{\log x})x$, which is clearly in $O(x)$ since $0 < 1-\frac{\log\log x}{\log x} < 1$ for $x$ sufficiently large.

Comment: And what diracdeltafunk wrote is as simple as it gets, unless you consider either $x(1- \log_x \log x)$ or $x- \log_x(\log x)^x$ to be a "simplification".